# Klarna API html_snippet returns "something went wrong"

Tags: klarna

I am trying to integrate the `Klarna Checkout API` but I keep getting the following error in the `html_snippet` of the result from the REST API Post request.

[image]

I have no idea why this error is appearing. What could be causing the problem. I am following the tutorial in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJ4Tmr8GJPo&t=38s&ab_channel=KlarnaTutorials).

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Comment: No, they never replied. Ended up switching to stripe.